# Python: msg.get_payload() discards needed data, solution wanted

Tags: python, regex, parsing, email, pop3

Hi I have gone through various posts here but none of them answer my question, I have two problems,
1.
I have written a script to get emails using poplib, everythig works fine until when I am trying to parse the body of the email it get rid of the  tags plus the data inside them, I  am now given up and am here for help hope you guys will guide me to the right direction as where I am doing wrong or what should I do to make it work.

Here's the source of parser script

```
import sys
import socket
import poplib
import email
import csv
import re
try:
  host = "mail.someserver.com"
  mail = poplib.POP3(host)
  print mail.getwelcome()
  print mail.user("username@someserver.com")
  print mail.pass_("qaiaJWkvZT")
  print mail.stat()
  print mail.list()
  print ""

  emailWriter = csv.writer(open('emailMessages.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='\'', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  emailWriter.writerow(['Messages'])
  if mail.stat()[1] > 0:
      print "You have new mail."
  else:
      print "No new mail."

  print ""

  numMessages = len(mail.list()[1])
  for i in range(numMessages):
      for j in mail.retr(i+1)[1]:
          #print j
          msg = email.message_from_string(j) # new statement
          print msg.get_payload(decode=True)
          #emailWriter.writerow([msg.get_payload(decode=True)]) # new statement

  mail.quit()
  input("Press any key to continue.")
except socket.error as e:
  print "Something went wrong! :(\nREASON:\n{0}:{1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
  raise
except:
  print "Something went wrong!", sys.exc_info()[0]
  raise
```

Here's the output the above script generates

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or
g/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
BODY {







}
TD {



}
TH {


}
H1 {

}
TABLE,IMG,A {

}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p><strong>PO Number:</strong> 35164</p>

<p><strong>Ship To:</strong><br />
Joe Pasloski<br />
16 Redwood Drive<br />Yorkton, SK  S3N2X7<br />
204-473-2218</p>


<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1" width="710" align="left">
<tr>



</tr>
<tr>



</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However if I change the script to print j variable directly inside the loop, it gives me this

```
Return-Path: <orders@someserver.com>
Delivered-To: username@someserver.com
Received: (qmail 7636 invoked by uid 48); 14 Jul 2012 23:29:11 -0000
Date: 14 Jul 2012 23:29:11 -0000
Message-ID: <20120714232911.7635.qmail@b.inetuhosted.net>
To: username@someserver.com
Subject: Drop Ship Order - Joe Pasloski
From: Someserver.com <orders@someserver.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.17
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
         boundary="2631183869_50020"
Reply-to: SomeServer.com <orders@someserver.com>
X-Antivirus: avast! (VPS 120714-2, 07/15/2012), Inbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean

--2631183869_50020
Content-Type: text/plain;
        charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit



--2631183869_50020
Content-Type: text/html;
        charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or
g/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
BODY {
        MARGIN-TOP: 10px;
        MARGIN-BOTTOM: 10px;
        MARGIN-LEFT: 10px;
        MARGIN-RIGHT: 10px;
        FONT-SIZE: 12px;
        FONT-FAMILY: arial,helvetica,sans-serif
        PADDING: 0px;
}
TD {
        FONT-SIZE: 12px;
        FONT-FAMILY: arial,helvetica,sans-serif
        COLOR: #000000;
}
TH {
        FONT-SIZE: 13px;
        FONT-FAMILY: arial,helvetica,sans-serif
}
H1 {
    FONT-SIZE: 20px
}
TABLE,IMG,A {
        BORDER: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p><strong>PO Number:</strong> 35164</p>

<p><strong>Ship To:</strong><br />
Joe Pasloski<br />
16 Redwood Drive<br />Yorkton, SK  S3N2X7<br />
204-473-2218</p>

<p><strong>Items:</strong>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1" width="710" align="left">
<tr>
        <th align="left" width="100">SKU</th>
        <th align="left" width="550">Product</th>
        <th align="left" width="60">Qty</th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>JJ-Hamper-Firetruck</td>
        <td>Frankie's Fire Truck Laundry Hamper</td>
        <td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If i need to process the raw message how can i effectively get the body part of the message stripping out the unnecessary html tags without losing any data? Or if it is possible through using get_payload() method, what can i do to make it work.

Please help!

2.
Further more is there a way I can get all the SKU information contained in the table using regex? if you can provide me that too that will be a plus. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer myself the documentation says all and the post at [Python: How to get HTML body of an email message using poplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668658/python-how-to-get-html-body-of-an-email-message-using-poplib) helped me move to the right direction.. As I known the messages I am dealing with are not of multipart type and while applying the get_payload() loses html data, That why I had to implement some regex routines to strip off the html tags from the raw message, for that I downloaded and used html2text library by Aaron Swartz on the raw message and then did msg.get_payload().. Here's what I have done

```
import html2text # added to my source
numMessages = len(mail.list()[1])
  for i in range(numMessages):
      for j in mail.retr(i+1)[1]:

          msg = email.message_from_string(html2text.html2text(j)) 
          print msg.get_payload(decode=False)
```

which in turn gave me

```
charset="iso-8859-1"











BODY {









}


TD {





}


TH {




}


H1 {



}


TABLE,IMG,A {



}










**PO Number:** 35170




**Ship To:**


Tami Curtis


67 E. Spring Creek Pkwy

Providence, UT 84332


4357553197









SKU


Product


Qty






JJ-Panel-Isabella-BK-PRT


Isabella Black Damask Curtains (2 Panels)


1
```

Now I just need to clean it up a bit more with regex to get reif of the unnecessary linefeeds/ whitespace and css markup also.

Hope it can be helpful for others too :) Cheers!